# Files appearing in Windows 8 "Network Locations"

Tags: windows-8

Today after restarting my computer I see this:

[image: word files appear beside map network drives in my computer]

This is my full screen snap shot. How is it that files can appear besides mapped network drives in `Network Location`?

How has this happened? Can I fix it? How to fix it? How can I add other files here?

My windows is Windows 8 and my computer is joined to a domain.

Comment: Right click on them, properties, and try to see where they originated.

Comment: Rather, these files are on the desktop.

Comment: @ekaj properties there are here : C:\Users\"USER_NAME"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts

Comment: @STTR no there arent on the desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ekaj mentioned in [the comment](https://superuser.com/questions/546197/actually-a-useful-trick-files-appearing-in-windows-8-network-locations#comment662735_546197)

> Right click on them, properties, and try to see where they originated.

I found that they are here

```
C:\Users\"USER_NAME"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
```

[image: network location]

Comment: That's actually a useful trick :) Feel free to mark your answer as the accepted answer